# What do you mean by non-radiative surface plasmons?

Tags: terminology, definition, plasma-physics, dispersion, plasmon

I would like to know if anyone can tell me what we meant by non-radiative Surface plasmons, when we look at the dispersion relations?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a single film, consisting of two dielectric materials of dielectric constants $\epsilon_1>\epsilon_2$ sandwiching a layer of gold, which we model using a Drude dielectric function,
$$
\epsilon_{\textrm{g}}=1-\frac{\omega_{\textrm{p}}^2}{\omega^2}\,,
$$
where $\omega_{\textrm{p}}$ is the plasma frequency in the gold.  After solving the electromagnetic wave equation in all three layers, applying the source-free condition that the divergence of the displacement field is zero, and applying electromagnetic boundary conditions at the interfaces, we arrive at an expression for the plasmonic dispersion relation.

[image]

The dispersion relation (shown above) consists of two regions, one which is to the right of all the light lines (defined by $\omega = \frac{c}{\sqrt{\epsilon_i}}k_x$), and the other which is between the two light lines (shaded in blue). The modes to the right of the light line are *localized* to the structure.  That is, the electric fields decay *exponentially* away from the device.  These modes are therefore considered *non-radiative* modes, because no fields can "escape" to infinity.  All the propagation occurs along the interfaces.  An example mode is shown below.

[image]

On the other hands, in between the light lines$-$also known as the "leaky" region$-$the modes are not localized to the structure.  Indeed, the field amplitudes *grow* exponentially away from the device into the material with the higher dielectric constant (in this in the negative $z$ direction). In addition, these modes can propagate away from the material, depending on the whether or not damping is included, etc. For these reasons, these modes are called **radiative modes**.  An example mode is shown below (the exponential growth into material 1 is very slow, but it's there!).

[image]

The possible modes supported by a single film were basically completely worked out in this paper:

[Surface-polariton-like waves guided by thin, lossy metal films](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.33.5186)
, Phys. Rev. B 33, 5186 – Published 15 April 1986.